# Replace atomic numbers in a column with the corresponding atomic symbols in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Can anybody tell me how can I replace atomic numbers in the first column of a file by the corresponding atomic symbols in bash script? I have many file to be replaced this way.

file:HCOOH

```
  6             0        -.134702     .401251    -.000249
  8             0       -1.134262    -.264582     .000069
  8             0        1.118680    -.091075     .000056
  1             0        -.107617    1.495465     .000513
  1             0        1.040484   -1.057714    -.000020
```

Desired Result:

```
  C             0        -.134702     .401251    -.000249
  O             0       -1.134262    -.264582     .000069
  O             0        1.118680    -.091075     .000056
  H             0        -.107617    1.495465     .000513
  H             0        1.040484   -1.057714    -.000020
```

My aim is to extract the geometry  of a system from the benchmark databases given in the supporting in formation of the paper "J. Chem. Theory Comput., 2005, 1 (3), pp 415–432 DOI: 10.1021/ct049851d" . As the atoms are given as the atomic numbers in the databases I can not use geometry directly in the NWCHEM code. Therefore I need to replace them with their corresponding symbols. Using the script

```
    #!/bin/bash
    atoms=(HCOOH H He Li Be B C N O F Ne)
    name="$(awk '{print $1}' HCOOH)"
    rm atom
    for j in ${name};
    do
     echo ${atoms[$j]} >>atom
    done
    awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{$1=a[FNR]}1' atom HCOOH | awk '{printf         "%-3s %-1s %10.5f %10.5f %10.5f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}'
```

I am getting

```
 HCOOH      0.00000    0.00000    0.00000
 C   0   -0.13470    0.40125   -0.00025
 O   0   -1.13426   -0.26458    0.00007
 O   0    1.11868   -0.09108    0.00006
 H   0   -0.10762    1.49547    0.00051
 H   0    1.04048   -1.05771   -0.00002
```

I could not escape zeros coming in the first line if the formatted output is required. I would be happy if someone can help to print the formatted output without printing zeros in the first line.

Thanks.

Finally, got the desired results using the script

```
    #!/bin/bash
    atoms=(HCOOH H He Li Be B C N O F Ne)
    name="$(awk '{print $1}' HCOOH)"
    rm atom
    for j in ${name};
    do
     echo ${atoms[$j]} >>atom
    done
    awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{$1=a[FNR]}1' atom HCOOH | awk 'NR==1{printf "%-3s\n", $1}' >tHCOOH
    awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{$1=a[FNR]}1' atom HCOOH | awk 'NR> 1{printf "%-3s %-1s %10.5f %10.5f %10.5f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' >>tHCOOH #| 
    mv tHCOOH HCOOH
```

which is

```
 HCOOH   
 C   0   -0.13470    0.40125   -0.00025
 O   0   -1.13426   -0.26458    0.00007
 O   0    1.11868   -0.09108    0.00006
 H   0   -0.10762    1.49547    0.00051
 H   0    1.04048   -1.05771   -0.00002
```

Let me know if there is a better way for getting the same output.
Thanks.

Comment: Post your research efforts in the question!

Comment: Okay, my aim is to extract the geometry  of a system from the benchmark databases given in the supporting in formation of the paper "J. Chem. Theory Comput., 2005, 1 (3), pp 415–432 DOI: 10.1021/ct049851d" . As the atoms are given as the atomic numbers in the databases I can not use geometry directly in the NWCHEM code.

Comment: We still do not see any code where we can help :-(

Comment: This site is not a code writing service. Please post your attempt and where it’s going wrong and ask for help about that.

Comment: Make a file called `atomic.txt` that contains `1 H` on the first line, `6 C` on the second line and `8 O` on the third. Then search StackOverflow for any `awk` answer that contains `FNR==NR`.

Comment: Dear Mark Setchell and others, Thank you very much for your response. I have added the script made in my question. The only problem left now is to escape the zeros in the first line of the formatted output. Thanks.

Comment: So in simple terms you want to replace the first column with the letters and strings?

Comment: I am nominating this question for reopening as OP has improved question considerably and attempted some code.